# VB6 library for creating Excel spreadsheets

Tags: vb6

I am trying to get a legacy app working on terminal services with the minimum amount of changes to the existing code base. 
What library for creating Excel spreadsheets using VB6 without having Excel installed could I use to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using COM Interop to create Excel spreadsheets you must have Excel installed on the machine.

You could create comma delimited .csv files instead.

Comment: +1 csv file creation is simple and works well and if excel is installed, it's the default program to open them

Answer (score 0):

CSV is easy as suggested in the other answer. Sometimes folk use HTML too.

[Create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c/151035#151035)

Or even ADO and OLEDB

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195951/